# Как изменять класс ссылки в Bootstrap <navbar> при переключении страниц через Angular router?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Есть навбар в app.component.html:

```
      <!-- NAVBAR -->
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">3Leaves <img src="./assets/3leaves.svg" alt="3Leaves"></a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/"><i class="fab fa-hotjar"></i> Горячие товары <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Популярные товары</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a class="nav-link"><i class="far fa-calendar-check"></i> Новые товары</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/new"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Добавить товар</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="nav-search mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Искать товар..." aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
<div class="cart-circle">
  <div class="circle">0</div>
  <a class="cart" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<!-- /NAVBAR -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
...
```

Как динамически убирать класс active у одной ссылки, и добавлять другой, на которой сейчас пользователь?

---

UPD.
изменил li class="nav-item" на li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active'] и убрал routerLink у неактивных ссылок. Теперь оно, помимо текущей, всегда отмечает главную страницу ("Горячие товары") как активную. Что можно сделать?

Скрин:
[image: Навбар]

Список всех активных ссылок на данный момент:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component:HotgoodsComponent},
    {path: 'new', component:ItemaddComponent}
]
```

Comment: читал документацию роутера и router link active ? )

Comment: изменил <li class="nav-item">...</li> на <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']>...</li>, теперь оно, помимо текущей, всегда отмечает главную страницу ("Горячие товары") как активную. Что можно сделать?

Comment: всегда - это когда?)

Comment: наверное стоит начать новый вопрос т.к. суть изменилась

Comment: в общем, описал новую проблему в отредактированном этом вопросе, ну а т.к. главная суть не решена, думаю правил не нарушаю

Comment: `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` попробуй

Comment: а это куда вписывать?

Comment: все, понял, помогло(вставил как атрибут тега li главной страницы)

Comment: напиши полное решение, чтоли, чтобы я отметил вопрос как решенный, помог все-таки

Comment: та ладно, это ж мини помощь :D